# Oracle PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm getting this error when I try to create this trigger. I tried everything but I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_price_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE new_totalprice INT;
BEGIN
   IF :OLD.price <> :new.price THEN
   new_totalprice := :old.Quantity * :new.price;
        INSERT INTO OrderRecord(OrderRecord_Id, Item_Id, Employee_Id, Reservation_Id, Order_Time, Quantity, TotalPrice)
        VALUES(old.OrderRecord_Id, old.Item_Id, old.Employee_Id, old.Reservation_Id, old.Order_Time, old.Quantity, new_totalprice);
    END IF;
END;
```

And the error is:

```
4/22      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.QUANTITY'
```

The tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    Item_Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Menu_Id int,
    Name varchar2(20),
    Description varchar2(120),
    Price int,
    FOREIGN KEY(Menu_Id) REFERENCES Menu(Menu_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderRecord (
    OrderRecord_Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Item_Id int,
    Employee_Id int,
    Reservation_Id int,
    Order_Time date,
    Quantity int,
    TotalPrice int,
    FOREIGN KEY(Item_Id)References Item(Item_Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(Employee_Id)References Employee(Employee_Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(Reservation_Id)References Reservation(Reservation_Id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Table OrderRecord is not the table being updated: you cannot reference an old value for this table; you need to read this value with some SELECT statement.

```
IF :OLD.price <> :new.price THEN
   new_totalprice := <Quantity> * :new.price;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column `Quantity` in the table `ITEM` on which you are applying trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are wanting to do correctly, it looks like you want to update the calculated total price of all existing `OrderRecord` entries when an `Item` entry has a price change.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_price_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NVL(:OLD.Price, 0) <> NVL(:new.Price, 0) THEN
    -- Update the child table "OrderRecord" for this item using new price
    UPDATE OrderRecord SET TotalPrice = Quantity * :new.Price WHERE Item_Id = :new.Item_id;
  END IF;
END;
```

Note that this trigger is on the parent table, `Item`, and references two values from the modified record: `price` and `Item_Id`, to update the child `OrderRecord` table.
Also note the use of `NVL` to watch for nulls because the comparison will not succeed if a null is on either side. Using zero for null is debatable; one could use a value that will never occur such as a negative number.